# Complex Computed Column in EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, entity-framework

I have an object that has a calculation field; The calculation formula is too complex, and it have to check some condition, and load some data from another objects (have to join with other tables). 
This is my Object:

```
public class LoadAndExitPermit : Master, IColorSource
{
    private int? _ladingBillId;
    [DataMember]
    public virtual int? LadingBillID
    {
        get { return _ladingBillId; }
        set { SetPropertyValue(ref _ladingBillId, value, "LadingBillID"); }
    }
    .
    . {lots of Properties)
    .
    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<LoadAndExitPermitDocumentDetail> LoadAndExitPermitDocumentDetails { get; set; }
```

The important part of my object is SumGoodsUnitPrice, and it's:

```
    [NotMapped, DataMember]
    Public decimal? SumGoodsUnitPrice
    {
        get
        {
            if (LoadAndExitPermitDetails == null || !LoadAndExitPermitDetails.Any())
            {
                return -1;
            }
            if (LoadAndExitPermitDetails.First().RequestDetail.OrderDetail == null)
            {
                decimal? sum = 0m;
                foreach (var item in LoadAndExitPermitDetails)
                {
                    decimal? tarrif = item.Good.GoodsTariffDetails.Where(g =>
                      g.Price > 0 && g.IsActive == true && g.GoodsTariff.GoodsTariffType.IsPublic == true && g.GoodsTariff.FromDate < Date)
                      .OrderByDescending(w => w.GoodsTariff.FromDate).Select(c => c.Price).FirstOrDefault();

                    if (tarrif != null)
                    {
                        sum += ((item.Quantity ?? 0) * (1.09m * (tarrif))) ?? 0m;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        decimal? lastTariff = item.Good.GoodsTariffDetails.Where(x => x.Price > 0 && x.IsActive == true
               && x.GoodsTariff.FromDate < Date).OrderByDescending(w => w.GoodsTariff.FromDate).Select(c => c.Price).FirstOrDefault() ?? 0m;
                        sum += ((item.Quantity ?? 0) * (1.09m * (lastTariff))) ?? 0;

                    }

                }
                return sum;

            }
            var z = LoadAndExitPermitDetails.Sum(l => (l.Quantity ?? 0) * (1.09m * (l.RequestDetail.OrderDetail.Quantity == 0 ? 0 : (l.RequestDetail.OrderDetail.Price / l.RequestDetail.OrderDetail.Quantity) ?? 0)));
            return z;

        }
        private set
        {

        }
    }
```

I have some Issues:

1. I can't use Projection, I have two reasons: first readability of the code and the 2th one is my project structure doesn't allow me to use projected query.
2. We use database first method and this field is not in database, because its calculated field.
3. We deal with a large database and I can't Include (join) all tables i need, so i prefer to use SQL service side query to calculate it for me.
4. We can't use Stored Procedure Or View, Because we have lots of this kind of columns, and we need to use dynamic query for dynamic filters.
5. The performance of query is very important for us.

**I would appropriate if anyone can help me.**

Comment: so what's the current issue with your code? You just described your issues as what you ***can't do*** but not showing any thing wrong with the current code.

Comment: i need to calculate this column on SQL server, with one round trip.

Comment: Can you put down the logic for calculation in words, so that i will be easier to interpret.

Comment: I don't understand how  "lots of this kind of columns", and "need to use dynamic query for dynamic filters" restrict using of Views.

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov I have lots of entities that include computed columns with complex formula.

Comment: @Nikita this is just a sample of calculation, for example i have to calculate the price, but price is not stored in the object and i have to retrieve data from another tables also the price depends on some condition ,...

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would add a view that calculate this field on the server and use it for queries. This is compatible with CQRS architectural pattern.

Comment: he cannot use a view as mentioned in his question, it could be rather a comment than an answer.

Comment: i have to use dynamic query and dynamic filters, so i cannot use view or SP

Comment: What do you mean by Dynamic filters and queries? How it permit using of views?

Comment: my end user can do anything(filtering) and i create expression to use in EF query and generated query.

Comment: I prefer to avoid using view with linq and EF

Comment: And view in scenario "user can do anything(filtering) and i create expression to use in EF query and generated query" works same as tables. You have only to cases in you problem: calculate on sql server with view and calculate on client with you current solution.